# Change Image Widget picture based on attribute table value of selected item in ArcGIS Online Experience Builder

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-online

I am trying to use the image widget using ArcGIS Online:

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/experience-builder/configure-widgets/image-widget.htm

But I would like the picture to changed based on the current point selected.  The image widget should show the image from an attribute field URL of selected point.  Is this going to be possible or with another widget?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, you have to configure the image widget to do it.

1. First create an Experience with a Map widget and an Image widget.
2. In the Image Widget settings, set these settings:

   - Connect to data
   - Image source: Dynamic
   - URL: Attribute
     [image]

[Example of this in action is here](https://experience.arcgis.com/experience/68fbe06a163349a6ab7bf4534229f0fc).